# 3D Graphics Acceleration

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.04, opengl, webgl

Grphics acceleration is disabled in Ubuntu. I went to `Software & Updates` and opened the `Additional Drivers` tab and was presented with a list of drivers, which one am I supposed to install?

Why is the correct driver not automatically selected and enabled during installation? This is really not user friendly, I can't even play a simple WebGL game (such as [apathy.plankhead.com](http://apathy.plankhead.com)) because it needs 3D acceleration.

Update:

I installed the "tested" nvidia drivers as per lupp0l0's recommendation and restarted my computer. Startup failed with a screen that said "[nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T5C1.jpg)".

After rebooting a few times, Ubuntu finally started. I'm worried that next time I restart Ubuntu will fail to load again.

Comment: Please, let us know which drivers you see from the "Additional Drivers" tab.

Comment: Sorry, i have a nvidia card so i can see nvidia-310, nvidia-310-updates, nouveau (currently selected) and some beta/legacy drivers.

Comment: Just as a quick note, WebGL does not always work, even if you do have the additional drivers. Blame the web browsers for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the Additional Drivers tab you see these three options:

nvidia-310: nvidia proprietary driver in the version available when your Ubuntu version was first released

nvidia-310-updates: nvidia proprietary driver in latest version available from the "updates" repository. If a new nvidia driver will be available in the next 9 month (support time for your Ubuntu 13.04) there is a good chance that it'll be installable through this option.

nouveau: open source version of the nvidia driver. This is default option because of its opensource license.

I advise you to choose "nvidia-310" for now.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. So the non-updates version is the safest option but I would prefer to be kept up to date. Is the "-updates" version just a gamble or is it generally stable as well?

Comment: For now the two options are the same and will install the same package. The nvidia-310-updates will be eventually be updated when nVidia will release a new driver version. I don't own a nVidia card, so I don't know if the -updates versions are generally stable.